# convert unequaled length list of string to dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I have a  list of string like this

```
["['List one', 'F, U','P']", 
"['List Two', 'J, C,  D,I']",     
"['List Three', 'W']",
"['List Four', 'Y, B','E, H, M','L, N']"]
```

And I'd list to convert it to a dictionary list like this

```
{
  List One: ['F','U','P'], 
  List Two: ['J','C','D','I'],     
  List Three: ['W'],
  List Four: ['Y', 'B','E','H','M','L', 'N']
}
```

I found similar examples but nothing close enough

Comment: updated answer to match latest question changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortest way:

```
import itertools
import re

res = {eval(i)[0]: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([re.split('\W+', j) for j in eval(i)[1:]])) for i in input_list}
```

Fastest way:

```
import itertools
import re

res = {}
for i in input_list:
    l = eval(i)
    res[l[0]] = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([re.split('\W+', j) for j in l[1:]]))
```

For added robustness, use `ast.literal_eval` instead of `eval` (suggested by [Maarten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1562285/maarten-fabr%c3%a9))

Comment: I would prefer `ast.literal_eval`  to `eval` to safely evaluate a string to a literal

Comment: I included single quotes to all the element in the list of strings. Can you twerk the code to reflect this change? Thanks